# What is the difference between hide() function and unset()?

Tags: 7, forms

What is the difference between `hide()` and `unset()`? I want to hide some elements, I found `hide()` and `unset()`, but I don't know which one I should use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`hide()` and `unset`() are not same.
hide() is a Drupal function and unset() is a raw php function.

`unset()` simply destroys a variable. 
For an example,

```
<?php
$name = 'Drupal';
unset($name);
print $name; // this will result an error as $name is no longer set. `isset()` will return FALSE.
```

`hide()` does NOT destroy the variable. It's useful to *mark* some render-able array is already rendered so it will not be **rendered again**.

it simply adds/replaces the given argument's `#printed` to TRUE so `drupal_render` or `render()` won't execute the theme functions again - instead, it will use cached version *if available*.

A sample use case of `hide()` would be to hide comment form in a node template and show it somewhere else in the template. You will also find it useful when altering pages or blocks. Do **NOT** `unset()` a render array if you want to use it somewhere else.

If you want to hide some specific form element from the user but still want to keep the form structure, set `#access` of the element to `FALSE`.

[hide()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7)

[drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7)

[unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)