# Make Title field "not required" or workaround how to prefill and hide it (drupal 9.2.8)

Tags: nodes, 9

On my site (drupal 9.2.8) users add content and there is no need to put any information to 'Title' field.
I was trying to make this field not required via form_alter in custom module but it did not work:

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form['#form_id'] == 'node_somenode_form' or $form['#form_id'] == 'node_somenode_form'){
    $form['title']['widget']['0']['#required'] = FALSE;    // not working
    $form['title']['widget']['#required'] = FALSE;    // not working
    $form['title']['#required'] = FALSE;    // not working
  }
}
```

As a workaround in my module I prefill Title using form_alter:

```
$form['title']['widget']['0']['value']['#default_value'] = 'any default title';
```

and then just hide this field from form. There are a few ways of doing that ([In form alter what is the different way of hiding fields and what is the difference between them?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/147623/in-form-alter-what-is-the-different-way-of-hiding-fields-and-what-is-the-differe/148779)
), I decided to use hide:

```
hide($form['title']);
```

but I am curies why `['#required'] = FALSE;` doesn't work for Title field but it works fine with other fields.

Comment: You can try this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183477/how-to-programmatically-create-a-title-for-a-new-node

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel):

> "Automatic Entity Label" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of entity label fields.